# filtering a DATETIMEOFFSET column to a local date range

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, timezone, datetimeoffset

If I have a [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) column in a SQL Server table, what's the right way to filter results to a range of local (not UTC) dates?  By "local" I mean date boundaries are relative to the timezone of each stored value (which may differ between rows), not relative to a single fixed local timezone.

I assume it's not this, because the [`DATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) literals will be assumed to be UTC. Correct?

```
WHERE EventTime >= '20140401' AND EventTime < '20140501'
```

So is this the right solution?

```
WHERE CAST (EventTime AS DATE) >= '20140401' AND CAST (EventTime AS DATE) < '20140501'
```

Or does the CAST function prevent efficient use of indexes on the `EventTime` column?  If so, what's the right way to "align" date literals on the same timezone as the DATETIMEOFFSET column?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can cast the `EventTime` column to a `date` type, which will strip away all time and offset information, leaving you with the local date.  But as you pointed out, there will be a performance cost if you cast the column at time of query.

You should consider creating a separate column of type `date` for this purpose.  You can do this in a view, or you can simply create a computed column.  You can then create an index on this column.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Events (
    EventID int NOT NULL,
    EventTime datetimeoffset NOT NULL,
    LocalDate AS (CONVERT(date, EventTime)),  -- this is the computed column
    CONSTRAINT PK_Events PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EventID)
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Events_LocalDate ON Events (
     LocalDate
)
```

You can then query by the `LocalDate` field and it will have the info you need and the appropriate index.